# vim syntax coloring for git commit messages in submodules

Tags: git, vim

I use git for version control and vim as my editor to enter git commit messages. Normally, the syntax for commit messages (bold red for commit heading, textwidth set to 72 etc.) works perfectly.

But if I am committing something inside a git submodule, then for some reason there is no syntax highlighting. Any clues why?

My OS is Linux, and I have `gitcommit.vim` in the following locations:

`/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/gitcommit.vim`

(no custom modifications in ~/.vim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check whether the *filetype* has been properly detected:

```
:setlocal filetype?
```

It should be `gitcommit`, set probably by this rule in `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.git/modules/**/COMMIT_EDITMSG setf gitcommit
```

Now, check whether you have this rule and whether the patch matches your environment. You may need to adapt this to catch your module's commit messages.

Comment: Bang on! I created a `filetype.vim` file in `~/.vim` containing that rule and life is good again! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! So you're running an older Vim version that doesn't yet have these definitions. You did exactly the right thing to fix it!